# Julia AMDGPU.jl launch configuration

Tags: julia, amd-gpu

I wonder if there is an equivalent (or something similar) of the `launch_configuration`
function in `CUDA.jl` that can be used in the `AMDGPU.jl` package? Otherwise, do you have any comments on how to know the configuration of the AMD GPU? Thanks.

Comment: Related to the AMDGPU package, is there some analogous to @cuDynamicSharedMem that is available in the CUDA package?